# Отлавливание дубликатов на вставке в базу

Tags: mysql, sql

На сайте организую "лайки", база данных выглядит так:

```
id_post | id_user
   1    |      2
   2    |      2
```

Как сделать проверку на уникальность записи по двум поля таблицы, чтобы не было дублирующихся "лайков", можно ли это сделать одним запросом, без проверки SELECT'ом?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: и что делать если есть? и по каким полям искать дубликаты?

Answer (score 3):

Я считаю, подойдёт UNIQUE-индекс **по двум** полям.

Comment: а при попытке добавить (без проверки существования) будет ошибка.

в любом случае вопрос не про индексы)

Comment: Если бы вопрос был про индексы, он был бы более конкретным. Индексы созданы в т.ч. и для решения подобных задач. Поэтому я предложил такое решение. Оно самое прозрачное и отделено от основной логики программы. Даже если логика сайта написана на СУБД, подобные вещи делать в логике -- не очень дальновидно.
И поясните, как разработчик может себе позволить не выполнять никаких проверок, если это предполагает работа с БД?

Comment: в данном случае я подразумеваю, что индексы есть.
я могу себе позволить в каких то случаях не проверять существование отдельным запросом, к примеру мне нужно добавить запись в базу, если  такого уникального, ессно, индекса нет в базе, либо обновить некоторые поля, если такой индекс есть. и сделаю я это insert .. on duplicate update. и никаких отдельных сапросов типа select мне делать совершенно не надо.

Comment: Так, простите, получается, что индекс нужен и только его наличие позволяет использовать расширенные конструкции языка запросов MySQL, не так ли?
Я соглашусь, что делать "проверку запросом" категорически дико.

Comment: ну вообщем-то да.

Answer (score 1):

у `INSERT` есть такая полезная штука как `ON DUPLICATE <какоето действие>`
гуглится по словам `INSERT ON DUPLICATE` ;)

Comment: и без unique индекса смысла данный ответ не имеет. а поскольку ответ не про индексы, то -1.

Comment: в данном случае я подразумеваю, что индексы есть.
я могу себе позволить в каких то случаях не проверять существование отдельным запросом, к примеру мне нужно добавить запись в базу, если  такого уникального, ессно, индекса нет в базе, либо обновить некоторые поля, если такой индекс есть. и сделаю я это insert .. on duplicate update. и никаких отдельных сапросов типа select мне делать совершенно не надо.

Comment: однако, меня начинает терзать смутное сомнение, что тут вообще без селекта не обойтись. так как и id_user и id_post МОЖЕТ повторяться, поотдельности. так что наверное я соглашусь с @Yura Ivanov

Answer (score 0):

`UNIQUE`-индекс (устранит дубли) + запрос `INSERT IGNORE INTO` (устранит ошибку).